# google maps api example in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to encode the example more simple of map following the manual (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) and not get see no map, although not get error.

The page is this: http://www.acuarelasmbt.com/mapa and is developed with wordpress CMS.

Could someone lend me a hand?

Comment: you should post the basics of what you have done, so we can see how we may be of assistance.

Comment: can you explain how you have done that and  show your code.

Comment: @bechapps .. Is it coming now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map is coming just need to add some width and height css to that div which is holding the map

Comment: the problem is - there is no `#map` div.

Comment: there is do  inspect  element or like view source .. just add some width and height css for #map

Comment: how did I miss it? but why does `document.getElementById(map)` return null?

Comment: try this document.getElementById("map")

Comment: yeah, already figured it out. such a little-bitch mistake. I feel really smart. :D

Comment: I add some width and height css to that div and works magically. Thanx everybody :)